# Click event is not working between the toggle bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" onclick="showNav();">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

I have this JS:

```
function showNav() {
    document.getElementById("dropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

and this CSS:

```
.navbar-toggle {
    margin-top: 15px;
    border: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    padding: 0;
    height: auto;
    &:focus {
        outline: 0;
    }
    .icon-bar {
        background-color: #fff;
        display: block;
        width: 22px;
        height: 2px;
        border-radius: 1px;
        background-color: #4F4644;
        margin-bottom: 4px;
        // &:before {
        //     content: "";
        //     height: 2px;
        //     background-color: #000000;
        //     width: 22px;
        //     margin-top: 5px;
        //     position: absolute;
        //     left: 0;
        //     top: -11px;
        // }
        // &:after {
        //     content: "";
        //     height: 2px;
        //     background-color: #000000;
        //     width: 22px;
        //     margin-top: 6px;
        //     position: absolute;
        //     left: 0;
        // }
    }
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Now, when I click on this, I am adding the `.show` class and then it's showing the `.dropdown-container` div which contain the menu items.

Now, sometimes it's not showing the `.dropdown-container` container because of the gap between the toggle.

**How can I implement the click event on the gap too?**

Comment: Suggestion: Avoid handlers on view. Instead add listeners using an initializer function from JS. **[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice)**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `dropdown` id does not exist. Not adding it would throw an exception when attempting to toggle. `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null"` **NOTE** It has been added below.

```js
function showNav() {
    document.getElementById("dropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.navbar-toggle.show {
    background-color: red;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    margin-top: 15px;
    border: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    padding: 0;
    height: auto;
    &:focus {
        outline: 0;
    }
}
  .icon-bar {
        background-color: #fff;
        display: block;
        width: 22px;
        height: 2px;
        border-radius: 1px;
        background-color: #4F4644;
        margin-bottom: 4px;
        // &:before {
        //     content: "";
        //     height: 2px;
        //     background-color: #000000;
        //     width: 22px;
        //     margin-top: 5px;
        //     position: absolute;
        //     left: 0;
        //     top: -11px;
        // }
        // &:after {
        //     content: "";
        //     height: 2px;
        //     background-color: #000000;
        //     width: 22px;
        //     margin-top: 6px;
        //     position: absolute;
        //     left: 0;
        // }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" id="dropdown" onclick="showNav();">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
```

**UPDATE**
If you are trying to toggle a class then you'll need to add the `show` for example: **NOTE** `navbar-toggle` for lack of a better word is coupled with the `show`, which can be toggled.

```
.navbar-toggle.show {
  background-color: red;
}
.navbar-toggle {
}
```

Comment: Let me try with this.

Comment: Minor suggestion: Add some style in your code for `.show`. This way if any reader click on it, they will see visible change and will not require to open dev tools just to validate it

Comment: @TheoNeUpKID still, when I click on the gap it's not working

Comment: @TheoNeUpKID `.show` class is already added using my JS code. and I have the `show` class already to make the `dropdown-container` as `block` but still between the toggle icon the click event is not working.

Comment: @Shibbir do you have a repo or could you include the snippet for rendering.

Comment: I have a repo but it's not password protected. I can share the full heder area code at here: https://codeshare.io/21do8z

Comment: Mmm.. I don't know you understand the issue or not. Please check this image: https://prnt.sc/voul8j. On this gap click event is not working.

Comment: Guess, keep at it. Here's a resource which should help. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_mobile_navbar.asp